# Google cache for home page shows the the Facebook page instead

Tags: seo, google, search-results, cache, google-cache

I have a very weird and kinda crazy problem with Google caching one of the pages on the website. At first, I thought I got hacked or something similar, I also talked to my host and they said there is nothing wrong with the hosting, files or websites.

Problem:

Well, I noticed that my page lost all rankings, I checked the cache of the page and it shows cached version of a totally different website it shows my Facebook page! I thought it will clear up on the next cache update, but it just did and its still the Facebook page.

*Screenshot:*

[image: See the problem in image]

*Google Cache:*

You can replicate the issue by taking a look at [cache:www.mehandi-designs.co.in](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.mehandi-designs.co.in/). I tried "fetch as googlebot" and it shows the proper code. I tried many other tools online that crawl the site with different user-agents and all show the right code.

I read some similar threads about this here, but none of them seemed to have solution.

Comment: Google does make mistakes. It happens, though rare. Use the Fetch as Google and then Submit to Index. Please understand this is not immediate. It can take a couple of days. There is nothing you can do about that, however, you can check your log files to see what happens as Google fetches your home page over the next couple of days. That may help.

Answer (score 2):

`Go To webmaster` -> `[property (website)]` -> `Crawl` -> `Fetch as Google`

Just hit `Fetch and Render`.

Then after it has fetched and rendered, you can again go the `Fetch as Google` screen and click on `Submit to Index` button.

Answer (score 2):

This is when you need to teach google a lesson.

Change or add a robots meta tag between `<head>` and `</head>` of the HTML code. It should look like this:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOARCHIVE">
```

This will cause google to NOT cache pages containing that tag on their website. Leave that meta tag in place until you are 100% sure your content isn't hacked. Then you can use the "fetch as google" tool to check all pages in question. Also, check your server configuration (such as .htaccess files) to see if certain IP addresses that attempt to connect to your site are redirected to another site.

Once everything is 100% perfect, then if you want, you can remove:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOARCHIVE">
```

Comment: just did as u said, lets see what happen

Comment: still same problem...ive changed my full webside files and then i fached as google but still google crawls facebook page

Comment: you'll have to give google time to understand the changes. I'd give them a week. They crawl other websites too, not just yours.